# How to use setPositivebutton

Tags: android

**How to set the setPositivebutton into another activity?**

Hi everyone, I am using android studio for this. I don't understand how to use let this button access into another activity. Is there anyone who knows how to correct it?

```
 private void checkoutConfirmation() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Checkout Confirmation");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure continue to checkout?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            global.clearCart();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Snackbar.make(view, "Checkout success", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            @Override
            public void onClick(dialogInterface builder, int Button) {
<!--the error of the code-->
                Intent intent = new Intent(CartFragment.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: is it fragment or activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you want to start MainActivity on click of the Positive Button. This can be done using below:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        global.clearCart();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Snackbar.make(view, "Checkout success", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Change CartFragment.this to getActivity() so that you can get the Activity Context here
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


    }
});
```

Comment: As an explanation: new Intent(...) wants a context as first parameter. Since Fragment does not extend Context, CartFragment.this is not working here. getActivity() on the other hand provides the activity of the fragment and Activity is extending Context so it can be used for the context parameter of the Intent constructor.